# I can't log in to Ubuntu one from windows client

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7

I needed to uninstall, and reinstall U1, in windows 7, then I have to wait on the "getting info, please wait" screen, after this, when I want to log in, then it says, "authentication failure". Then I tried to reset my passworld, and then it tells me, I'm not even registered.
From the web interface, I can log in.
Anyone has ever experienced this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the 3.0 Windows update we are rolling back the update due to a bug. We are recommending all users so back to using 2.0.3 until bug is fixed. We have been seeing a lot of authentication issue.

Here are the steps:

1. Uninstall Ubuntu One
2. Restart your computer
3. Download http://one.ubuntu.com/windows/ubuntuone-2.0.3-windows-installer.exe and install it and let us know if that worked for you or not

Comment: worked for me too, on W7 Pro 64bits

Comment: this answer is not usefull anymore. Please read my comment bellow.