# Auth failed error on windows 7 ultimate

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7, authentication

after installing ubuntu one on windows 7 ultimate, when i try to log in, Ubuntu gives me back the message :`The authentication failed`.

Oh, it's OK. Perhaps I've forgotten the pass. So i clicked `I've forgotten my password`, but when i enter my mail address, Ubuntu tells me `Sorry, we did not recognize the email address`.

But i can sign in with no problem using the browser... any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to run Ubuntu in text mode, or after booting press 

    Alt+Ctrl+F1

and try to log in, does it work?

Comment: @Misery I think he is asking problems with ubuntu one client in windows 7

Comment: Oh, ok :) I thought it was dual boot.

Answer (score 1):

Not an actual answer but it looks like an unusual number of these popping up, for example see [I can't log in to Ubuntu one from windows client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123768/i-cant-log-in-to-ubuntu-one-from-windows-client).  The answer seems to come from a credible source though for me the latest version cured a number of problems.  I did however need to reboot before I restarted the Ubuntu One service for it to to work properly. My case is different however because I am on 32 bit XP.

Comment: Please notice that after that answer was given, we have rolled out a fixed 3.0.0, so we are very interested on getting bug reports if these problems persist.

Comment: With 3.0.1, it doesn't work either. I didn't try resetting the passwords, but I tried it often and it worked always through the web interface, never in the installation routine.